# Passing an array to feed svg.js's polyline array method throws an error

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg.js

I'm using [svg.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.js)'s polyline array method to draw lines from values logged by storing the cursor's x,y coordinates on a page.

The idea is to first let a user browsing the page and move the cursor around, and so feed values into the array, then when clicking on a button svg.js will draw lines based on the cursor' movement.

Being [this](http://documentup.com/wout/SVG.js#polyline) the syntax to follow:

```
var polyline = draw.polyline([[0,0], [100,50], [50,100]]).fill('none').stroke({ width: 1 })
```

if I manually copy-paste the values in the array as in:

```
var polyline = draw.polyline([[475,76], [475,76], [489,75], (...)]]).fill('none').stroke({ width: 1 });
```

svg.js works as expected.

If I pass in a variable, it tells me this:

```
svg.js:2632 Error: <polyline> attribute points: Expected number, "NaN,528 NaN,531 …".
```

This is my code:

```
// movement
var array_cursor_movement = [];
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var cursor_movement = "["+ e.pageX +","+ e.pageY +"]";
  array_cursor_movement.push(cursor_movement);
  var cursor_movement = array_cursor_movement.join(', ');
  console.log("movement:" + cursor_movement);

  localStorage.setItem("cursor_movement_pos", JSON.stringify(array_cursor_movement));
});

// click for preview lines
$(".preview--lines, .close--button").click(function(){
  $(".preview").toggleClass("show--hide");
  // draw lines
  var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("cursor_movement_pos");
  var array_cursor_movement_b = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
  var cursor_movement = array_cursor_movement_b.join(', ');
  cursor_movement =  "["+cursor_movement+"]";
  console.log("preview:" + cursor_movement);

  var width  = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var draw = SVG('drawing').size(width, height);
  var polyline = draw.polyline(cursor_movement).fill('none').stroke({ width: 1 });
})
```

Anyone has experience?

Thanks,
André

Comment: You dont pass an array to polyine. You made it to a string before. `var cursor_movement = array_cursor_movement_b.join(', ');
  cursor_movement =  "["+cursor_movement+"]";`

Comment: Make sure your string is in the required form `x,y x,y x,y` . There is no whitespace around comma but it seems your code inserts white space after the comma like x, y by `.join(', ')`

Comment: @Redu not necessary. He just has to push the array and not the joined string. Op already mentioned what the correct syntax is. He just has to do it

Comment: @Fuzzyma Thanks for the prompt reply! I got a bit confused: this `var cursor_movement = array_cursor_movement_b.join(', ');` already turns the array into a string; and this `cursor_movement = "["+cursor_movement+"]"` wraps the string `[x,y], [x,y]` into a `[]`. Or is this wrong? js newbie here.

Comment: dont do that! just pass the array not the string!!!

Comment: @Fuzzym I cleaned up the code and passed the array to be read by `draw.polyline` but now I still get the same error `Error: <polyline> attribute points: Expected number, "[718,124],[641,9…".` Those values are the exact ones I have in the array.

Here a [codepen](http://codepen.io/afincato/pen/grjdNg). Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments: Stop making Strings!! Just pass the array!

```
// movement
var array_cursor_movement = [];
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  // var cursor_movement = "["+ e.pageX +","+ e.pageY +"]"; // NO - stop making strings!
  var cursor_movement = [ e.pageX, e.pageY ];

  array_cursor_movement.push(cursor_movement);
  // var cursor_movement = array_cursor_movement.join(', '); // STOP
  console.log("movement:", cursor_movement);

  localStorage.setItem("cursor_movement_pos", JSON.stringify(array_cursor_movement));
});

// click for preview lines
$(".preview--lines, .close--button").click(function(){
  $(".preview").toggleClass("show--hide");

  // draw lines
  var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("cursor_movement_pos");
  var array_cursor_movement_b = JSON.parse(retrievedData);

  // var cursor_movement = array_cursor_movement_b.join(', ');  // what did I say?
  // cursor_movement =  "["+cursor_movement+"]";
  // console.log("preview:", cursor_movement);

  var width  = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var draw = SVG('drawing').size(width, height);

  // just pass the array and not the string
  var polyline = draw.polyline(array_cursor_movement_b).fill('none').stroke({ width: 1 });
})
```

PS: Corrected Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMjgdO

// EDIT: I guess I make things more clear:
As you said yourself the syntax to create a polyline is as follows:

```
var polyline = draw.polyline([[0,0], [100,50], [50,100]]).fill('none').stroke({ width: 1 })
```

But you tried to do this instead:

```
var polyline = draw.polyline("[[0,0], [100,50], [50,100]]").fill('none').stroke({ width: 1 })
                             ^ you notice the quotes here?
```

So you did not pass an array to the function. You passed a string which looks like an array.

Note that there is another syntax to create a polyline which is:

```
var polyline = draw.polyline('0,0 100,50 50,100').fill('none').stroke({ width: 1 })
```

So you actually CAN pass a string. It just is a comma and space seperated list. But DONT do that. You already created your array. You dont need the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you patience! I just read about arrays and strings the other day and now they're a bit more clear.